# In IOS 13.2 MFMailComposeViewController send and cancel buttons are not appearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Also when we disable keypad Im unable to see entered email Id.

I tried:

```
[[emailer navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

[image]

Comment: Did you implement the delegate method and properly assign the delegate?

Comment: Yes I implemented it 3 years back, all is working well but in latest IOS 13+ versions its giving this issues.

Comment: Any update on this? Having same issue in ios13

Comment: I also came across this same [behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58656920/1077789).