# MFMailComposeViewController behaves differently in iOS 13 simulator and device

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, xcode11

I'm trying to display `MFMailComposeViewController` in an app.

```
if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
    let mailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposeViewController.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
    mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailComposeViewController.setToRecipients(["support@gmail.com"])
    mailComposeViewController.setSubject("Feedback")
    present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true)
} else {
    print("This device is not configured to send email. Please set up an email account.")
}
```

In iOS 12, it shows up without an issue. In both simulator and device.

[image]

But when I run the same project on a device running iOS 13, it looks like this.

[image]

The navigation bar color is gone. Also the send button is also invisible.

So I added `mailComposeViewController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .mv_primary` but it still doesn't show on the device. Strangely the background color shows in the simulator.

However there's a strange behavior. The `MFMailComposeViewController` immediately dismisses by itself when I run it in the simulator.

[image]

The following error also shows up in the Xcode console.

> [Common] [FBSSystemService][0x5f27] Error handling open request for
>   com.apple.MailCompositionService:  {
>       userInfo = {
>           FBSOpenApplicationRequestID = 0x5f27;
>       }
>       underlyingError = ; } 2019-11-01
>   14:40:05.214158+0530 MailCompose[11289:262267] [Assert] Connection
>   request invalidated without resuming our _serviceSessionConnection.
>   This is an error. 2019-11-01 14:40:05.216901+0530
>   MailCompose[11289:262054] [General] #CompositionServices
>   _serviceViewControllerReady: NSError Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=0

I guess the weird dismiss error is a Xcode bug. But how do I fix the background color and the send button not showing up in the device?

This is how I set all the navigationbar related styles.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .mv_primary
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
}
```

[Demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q8o5vwd9zozcv24/mailcompose.zip?dl=0)

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem on iOS 13.3. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @inankupeli Unfortunately no. I posted the same question on Apple Developer forums as well but no response there as well.

Comment: @Isuru have you found out any solution?

Comment: @Isuru In the question you mentioned that you are trying to run it in the simulator, however this cannot be tested in the simulator you need a device for that, the default modal presentation in iOS 13 is page sheet, can you try changing the modal presentation to fullscreen and see if you get the same behavior? Does this respond the same way in device as well?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line of code before present it. It will work normal. This a change in iOS 13

```
mailController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the Mail composer dismisses immediately is because you can't actually send an email from the simulator. The implementation is different from iOS itself.

What I guess is happening here is that while the simulator implementation uses just some normal UI elements, the `MFMailComposeViewController` on native iOS is actually **hosted** like `UIDocumentPickerViewController` or `UIActivityViewController`. This means screenshots and trying to traverse the view tree is impossible, because the view is not an actual part of your application. They do that because these controllers contain user private information. Hosted view controller do NOT allow for customization, and do not comply with your global `UINavigationBar.appearance()`. This would explain why it does show up in the simulator and not on your native device.

Answer (score 1):

This is new UI Style from iOS 13. You can disable it in Storyboard or set manual.
[Presenting modal in iOS 13 fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435510/presenting-modal-in-ios-13-fullscreen)